# Filtering dataframe for unique observations in R, regardless of column 1 or 2

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following worked example.

```
person_A <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,6)
person_B <- c(3,4,5,9,1,1,8,7,1,3,7,6,5)

df1 <- data.frame(person_A, person_B)
```

So in each row we have an ID of `person_A` and `person_B`

I want to filter `df1` and remove the duplicate combinations of `person_A` and `person_B` and only have the unique combinations as an output. **But, we must check the switched combinations** (between `person_A`--`person_B` and `person_B`--`person_A`)

In other words, I want to remove the parts shaded in red

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `duplicated`.  We use `apply` to `sort` the elements by row (`MARGIN = 1`), then transpose the output, use `duplicated` to find the duplicate elements as logical `vector`, negate (`!`), and subset only the `unique` rows

```
df1[!duplicated(t(apply(df1, 1, sort))),]
```

Comment: simple but elegant. i like a lot